# bounded real part then removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ is analytic on $R<|z|<+\infty$, and $|\mathrm{Re}f(z)|\leq M$. The Laurent series Expansion 
 $$f(z)=\varphi(z)+\psi(z),$$ 
where $\varphi(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$  is the principal part of $f(z)$ at $\infty$. Show that  $\mathrm{Re} \varphi(z)$ is bounded, and then prove $\varphi(z)$ is constant, so $\infty$ is a removable singularity of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1) What do you know about the behaviour of $\psi(z)$ as $|z| \to \infty$?

2) Do you know the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Please in detail. Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you done so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks! ok!  $R'>\mathrm{R}$, $\psi(z)$ is bounded on $ R'\leq|z|<+\infty$, so is $\mathrm{Re}\psi(z)$.then $\mathrm{Re}\varphi(z)$ is bounded on $ R'\leq|z|<+\infty$, too.    $\varphi(z)$ is an entire function,  so $\varphi(z)$ is bounded on $ |z|\leq R'$. we get that $\mathrm{Re}\varphi(z)$ is bounded on $ \Bbb C$. then,we have two ways.1).According to Liouville theorem, $ \varphi(z)$ is constant.  Or 2) According to Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, $\infty$ is not an essential singularity of $f(z)$; According to Fundamental Theorem of  Algebra，$\infty$ is not a pole  of $f(z)$

Comment: 1) The Liouville theorem would work if you knew $\varphi$ was bounded, but you only know about $\text{Re}(\varphi)$.
2) You want to apply Casorati-Weierstrass and Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to $\varphi$, not to $f$.

Comment: Thanks! en. $\mathrm{Re}\varphi(z)$ was bounded, it was easy to prove $\varphi(z)$  was constant with Liouville theorem. every textbook contain this proof; 2) yes, I apply  Weierstrass and Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to  $\varphi(z)$